# Using Point Data to Predict Similar Occurrences in the Future?

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation

To provide a brief background: I have 5 years of conflict point data which is  just a cluster of all years together. Additionally, I have point locations of power plants. The goal is to use the temporal conflict data to predict locations of future conflict points around the power plant locations.

Is it possible to use an average annual locational occurrence to predict future locations of conflict?

Comment: This is a big statistical question that would need a lot of clarification of the structure of your data and what you are trying to predict, and its relationship to covariates like the power plant locations. You'd need to express all this mathematically and then fit a statistical model, possibly a spatio-temporal point-pattern, that would give P(conflict at S in time T) and the uncertainty on that.

Comment: "Is is possible" Questions are somewhat problematic since the answer is almost always "Yes," but that can range from "Yes, of course" to "Yes, if you put an obscene level of effort, but the results will likely not be particularly useful." This seems to be one of the latter.